# Move the Content Element in all languages

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have a multiple language website.
I'm using the TYPO3 Backend to move many content elements from page to page, but this move the CE only in one lang, but i would like to do it only once, so if i move a Content from page 4 to 8, it should be done in all the 4 languages.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the moving in the List module. In List module you can mark the records for all languages at the same time and put them into the clipboard.

Comment: We have list module disactivated so they can't use it unfortunately.

Comment: you can fill the (multi element) clipboard also from page view. but that would mean to switch to all languages and add the appropriate CEs, which is error prone.